# there isn't NotificationCompat in my eclipse

Tags: android

i am learning android programming by developer.android  this website use "NotificationCompat" class for create notification.but in my eclipse don't has this class  what can i do???  work with api-14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NotificationCompat is in the support library.
You don't need to use it if you don't support API levels < 11.

If your minimum API Level is > 10, use the Notification object instead of the NotificationCompat.

Answer (score 0):

NotificationCompat is part of the v4 Support Library the Android team is publishing to add new features to older Android versions as well.

To add the support library to your project, right-click your project, Android-Tools > Add Support Library > Revision 19 > Accept > Install